Storing data in SQL table in long format
I have a set of data that I want to store in a sqlite3 (though I'm considering other options as well) table. The issue is I want to store this data in long format, but many of the columns have the same values for multiple rows in long format.
e.g., suppose I have columns col1, col2, col3, col4, ..., col10 where the first 6 columns will have the same values for every group of 10 rows. So from a storage perspective this seems rather wasteful. Are there optimizations that can be made in the schema for this?

You're likely overthinking this. You'll be surprised how little space this requires, even for a few million rows. But if you really want, the way to handle that is adding a table with this columns plus an incrementing key, and then only storing the key in the existing table.

I'm not familiar with this term "long" format ... what does it mean to store data in a database in long format? Although in general it sounds exactly like what Joel said - just like if you have an address that is shared by 10 persons ... you can store the addresses in an addresses table and the other tables only store a key to the address.

"from a storage perspective this seems rather wasteful" - Measure it.  How many truly duplicate values are being stored, and what total storage space do those values require?  If you were to normalize this data into a central table for lookups and store a key to a record in that table instead, what is the new total space used?  Is the reduction in storage space achieved worth the complexity added?  What is the cost of more storage space vs. the cost of development and support time for the added complexity?

if your Idea was valid one, it would be implemented a long time ago. For example in .net, thanks to the string interning, system does not duplicate string objects and only duplicates pointers. This is similar to what you're trying to do. But string can be large object while your case is just numeric data.

Ultimately this is probably question of database normalization vs complexity and compute costs. I don't believe I've run across any compression feature set that would work in this columnar direction, but even if there were, you'd still face the same question of storage cost vs retreival time and/or compute. Before heading in any direction, I would test to see if this is an actual problem that needs to be solved.
